# Remove lines contain \N in the file

Tags: regex, bash, awk, sed

I have a file that uses \N for missing data.
How can I remove the lines with this wild character.

I used `sed '/\\N/d'` but it seems it is remove more lines that I expected.

input:

```
AA \N
BB .3
CC .4
DD \N
```

Since both `sed '/\\N/d'` and `LC_ALL=C grep -vF '\N'` produce the same results, there is something wrong that I can not figure out. The file is 7G and 200M lines. After removing `\N` lines only 25M lines has remained. Checking the file  with `less` does not indicate that much `\N`!

Comment: Your command looks fine to me.

Comment: It's also a good idea to post your desired output.

Comment: In fact, the file is huge, I am checking it with grep -vF '\N' to see if I can get the same result or not.  
 
If both grep and sed produce the same results then I will delete the question.

Comment: If you are seeing strange results with `sed` and `grep` I suspect it's a line ending issue, please post the output from running `file` on your input file.

Comment: The file is 7GB and the grep function is still running!

Comment: Grep will run much quicker if you change your locale. Try `LC_ALL=C grep -vF '\N' file`

Comment: Much faster! same results! But I cannot delete the question.

Comment: Then its a line ending issue, you can use `dos2unix` to convert line endings from Windows style to Linux style.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With `grep`:

```
$ grep -vF '\N' file
BB .3
CC .4
```

Options: `-v` for an inverse match and `-F` for a fixed string search *(not regex)*.

Comment: Yeah, that works too, although it remains unclear what the problem is with the OP's original command.

Answer (score 0):

The problem with your regex is that it will remove all lines containing '\N'.

Say file has values

A\N 0.3

B\NC 0.4

CC 0.5

DD \N

Even if you wanted to remove line 'DD \N', the other lines viz. A\N 0.3 & B\NC 0.4 will also be removed.

If '\N' is always towards the end of the line you can use the below regex.
Please note the **-r** . This is required for extended regex.

```
sed -r '/(\\N+$)/d'
```